# Microsoft Access Database values replaced with ################

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb, corruption

Having a strange issue with a c# system I have created that involves multiple users over a network accessing a Microsoft Access Database via OleDb. It seems as though random values are being replaced with a string of 16 hash symbols.

I can't seem to find anything on google on this issue, does anyone know what the hash symbols represent or what causes them? Could it be to do with corruption?

Here's a screenshot of part of the table in MS Access:

[image: Screenshot of MS Access]

EDIT: No, it's not to do with column with. This actual values have been replaced with hash symbols.

[image: Zoom of a value]

Comment: Is it just because the column isn't wide enough to display the values?

Comment: Access will display hash marks if the field values are wider than the column width. Try expanding them.

Comment: Are you sure the windows and formatting of everything is correct. MSFT likes to show # signs when formatting/window size is wrong

Comment: With that table open in Datasheet View in Access, place the cursor in one of those `#` filled fields and then press Shift+F2 to display the value in a Zoom window.  What does the Zoom window show you as the actual value?

Comment: @DavidG Nope, I thought people might say that!

Comment: @DGibbs it's not the problem, updated my question

Comment: @HansUp edited my question and added screenshot of zoom window

Comment: Does the `#` character replacement happen only through your c# app?  If it never happens when you use only Access itself to interact with the the data (insert, update, delete), I don't believe database corruption is the cause.

Comment: @HansUp I don't use access to interact with the data, and have never come across the problem with my personal testing, problems only occur when my client's company are using it (multiple pcs running application instances which access a single access database file over a network)

Comment: I vaguely remember that a commercial ODBC driver would do this, when it was unlicensed (i.e. in trial mode). Having never used OLEDB I don't know if there are commercial drivers, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Andre in what circumstances would it occur? randomly, or under reproducible conditions?

Comment: So what OLEDB provider *are* they using? (The connection string might offer a clue.)

Comment: @mbdavis: I can't really remember, but I think it was random.

Comment: @Andre Argh. That's annoying. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GordThompson Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: Okay, then my idea is most probably not the issue.